# High Memory issues in .net framework 4 but not in framework 4.5

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a following piece of code (.net 4) that is consuming a lot of memory:

```
struct Data
{
    private readonly List<Dictionary<string,string>> _list;

    public Data(List<Dictionary<string,string>> List)
    {
        _list = List;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        int num = 0;
        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> d in _list)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in d)
                num += Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value);
        }

        Console.Write(num);

        //_list = null;
    }
}

class Test1
{
    BlockingCollection<Data> collection = new BlockingCollection<Data>(10);
    Thread th;

    public Test1()
    {
        th = new Thread(Work);
        th.Start();
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> l = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<100000; i++)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            d["1"]  = r.Next().ToString();
            d["2"]  = r.Next().ToString();
            d["3"]  = r.Next().ToString();
            d["4"]  = r.Next().ToString();

            l.Add(d);
        }

        collection.Add(new Data(l));
    }

    private void Work()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            collection.Take().DoWork();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    Test1 t = new Test1();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            p.t.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The size of blocking collection is 10. In my knowledge, gc should collect references in 'Data' struct as soon its DoWork method is complete. However, the memory keeps on increasing at a rapid rate until the program crashes or it come down on its own and this is happening more often on low end machines (on some machines memory does not increase).Further, when I add the following line "_list = null;" at the end of DoWork method and convert 'Data' into class (from struct), memory does not increase.

What could be happening here. I need some suggestions here.

Update: the issue is occuring on machines with .net framework 4 installed (4.5 **not** installed)

Comment: Any reason you've made `Data` a `struct` rather than a `class`?

Comment: Actually the code is 'inherited'. There is no reason, but can it effect memory.

Comment: Can you please fix your code? The class names don't fit (eg. Program/Test1 ??) Calling the Work and Read methods?

Comment: @Euphoric code is updated.

Comment: Your code seems to be working properly. For me the memory hovers between 150MB to 300MB and is disposed properly. Tried .NET 4/4.5 with both release and debug.

Comment: Thanks Euphoric. I am using 32 bit windows 7, core 2 duo, with 4 Gb ram. The program is throwing outofmemory error on my machine. But when I change struct to class and make list null, there are no issues. Also reproduced it on 2 more machines.

Comment: With exactly same code? I tried forcing it into 32b and it still works properly. Only difference I see is that I'm using Windows 8 and x64, but that shouldn't be problem if I force it to run in 32bit

Comment: After a bit of effort... the issue is occuring on machines with .net framework 4 installed (4.5 not installed).

Comment: Perhaps it's something to do with the `while(true)` in your `Work` method?

Comment: I can confirm this behavior with .NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2003 R2 32 Bit. The memory keeps increasing till 1.5 GB, then gets garbage collected to reduce memory to 500 MB, and then it goes up again to 1.5 GB. But it is not crashing.

Comment: If you take a look at BlockingCollection with a tool such as .NET Reflector, you will see a lot of differences between .NET 4 vs the latest 4.5 version (which does not correspond to the 4.5Update1 listed here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx BTW). For example, the internal m_isDisposed fiedl is now marked volatile. So, yes, it's been changed, possibly fixed. What kind of answer do you want exactly?

Comment: Actually, I want to know, how using structs and setting list to null is effecting the process of garbage collection in 4.0. Setting an object to null, after its usage, is a practise not generally followed. If it 'has' to be done (due to an issue in .net 4) then we might have to review our production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read [Stephen Toub's explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/05/08/concurrentqueue-lt-t-gt-holding-on-to-a-few-dequeued-elements.aspx) of how `ConcurrentQueue` works, the behavior makes sense. `BlockingCollection` uses `ConcurrentQueue` by default, which stores its elements in linked lists of 32-element segments.

For the purposes of concurrent access, elements in the linked list are never overwritten, so they don't get unreferenced until the last of a whole segment of 32 is consumed. Since you have a bounded capacity of 10 elements, let's say that you have produced 41 elements and consumed 31. That means you will have one segment of 31 consumed element plus one queued element, and another segment with the remaining 9 elements. At this point all 41 elements are referenced, so if each element is 25MB, your collection will be taking up 1GB! Once the next item is consumed, all 32 of the elements in the head segment will be unreferenced and can be collected.

You may think there should only ever need to be 10 elements in the queue, and that would be the case for a non-concurrent queue, but that would not allow one thread to enumerate the elements in the queue while another thread was producing or consuming elements.

The reason that the .Net 4.5 framework doesn't leak is that they changed the behavior to null out elements as soon as they're produced as long as there is nobody enumerating the queue. If you start enumerating `collection`, you should see memory leak even with the .Net 4.5 framework.

The reason that setting `_list = null` works when you have a `class` is that you are creating a "box" wrapper that allows you to unreference the list in every place that it's used. Setting the value in your local variable changes the same copy that the queue has a reference to.

The reason that setting `_list = null` doesn't work when you have a `struct` is that you can only ever change copies of a `struct`. The "original" version of it sitting in that queue segment is effectively immutable because `ConcurrentQueue` doesn't provide a way to change it. In other words, you're changing only the copy of the value in your local variable rather than chaging the copy in the queue.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 6):

I've tried on my computer here are the result:

1. With Data as class and without `_list = null` at the end of DoWork -> memory increases
2. With Data as struct and without `_list = null` at the end of DoWork -> memory increases
3. With Data as class and with `_list = null` at the end of DoWork -> memory stabilizes at 150MB
4. With Data as struct and with `_list = null` at the end of DoWork -> memory increases

In the cases where `_list = null` is commented, it is not a surprise to see this result. Because there is still a reference to the _list. Even if `DoWork` is never called again, the GC can not know it.

In the third case, the garbage collector have the behavior we expect it to have.

For the fourth case, the BlockingCollection stores the `Data` when you pass it as argument of in `collection.Add(new Data(l));`, but then what is done?

1. The a new struct `data` is created with `data._list` equals to `l` (ie as the type `List` is a class (reference type), `data._list` equals in the struct `Data` to the address of `l`).
2. Then you pass it as argument in `collection.Add(new Data(l));` then it creates a copy of the `data` created in 1. Then the address of `l` is copied.
3. The blocking collection stores your `Data` elements in an array.
4. When `DoWork` executes `_list = null`, it removes the reference to the problematic `List` only in the current struct, not in all the copied version that are stored in the `BlockingCollection`.
5. Then, you have the problem unless you clear the `BlockingCollection`.

### How to find the problem?

To find memory leak problem, I suggest you to use SOS ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx ).

Here, I present how I have found the issue. As it is a issue that imply not only the heap but also the stack, using heap analysis (as here) is not the best way to find the source of the problem.

**1** Put a breakpoint on `_list = null` (because this line should work !!!)

**2** Execute the program

**3** When the breakpoint is reached, load the SOS Debugging Tool (Write ".load sos" in the Immediate Window)

**4** The problem seems to come from the `private List> _list` that is note disposed correctly. So we'll try to find the instances of the type. Type `!DumpHeap -stat -type List` in the Immediate Window. Result:

```
total 0 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
0570ffdc        1           24 System.Collections.Generic.List1[[System.Threading.CancellationTokenRegistration, mscorlib]]
04f63e50        1           24 System.Collections.Generic.List1[[System.Security.Policy.StrongName, mscorlib]]
00202800        2           48 System.Collections.Generic.List1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib]]
Total 4 objects
```

The problematic type is the last one `List<Dictionary<...>>`. There are 2 instances and the MethodTable (a kind of reference of the type) is `00202800`.

**5** To get the references, type `!DumpHeap -mt 00202800`. Result:

```
 Address       MT     Size
02618a9c 00202800       24     
0733880c 00202800       24     
total 0 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00202800        2           48 System.Collections.Generic.List1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib]]
Total 2 objects
```

The two instances are shown, with their addresses: `02618a9c` and `0733880c`

**6** To find how they are references: Type `!GCRoot 02618a9c` (for the first instance) or `!GCRoot 0733880c` (for the second). Result (I have not copied all the result but kept an important part):

```
ESP:3bef9c:Root:  0261874c(ConsoleApplication1.Test1)->
  0261875c(System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection1[[ConsoleApplication1.Data, ConsoleApplication1]])->
  02618784(System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue1[[ConsoleApplication1.Data, ConsoleApplication1]])->
  02618798(System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue1+Segment[[ConsoleApplication1.Data, ConsoleApplication1]])->
  026187bc(ConsoleApplication1.Data[])->
  02618a9c(System.Collections.Generic.List1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib]])
```

for the first instance, and:

```
Scan Thread 5216 OSTHread 1460
ESP:3bf0b0:Root:  0733880c(System.Collections.Generic.List1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib]])
Scan Thread 4960 OSTHread 1360
Scan Thread 6044 OSTHread 179c
```

for the second one (when the analyzed object has not deeper root, I think it means it has reference in the stack).

Looking at `026187bc(ConsoleApplication1.Data[])` should be a good way to understand what happen, because we finally see our `Data` type.

**7** To display the content of object, use `!DumpObj 026187bc`, or in this case, as it is an array, use `!DumpArray -details 026187bc`. Result (partial):

```
Name:        ConsoleApplication1.Data[]
MethodTable: 00214f30
EEClass:     00214ea8
Size:        140(0x8c) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 32, Type VALUETYPE
Element Methodtable: 00214670
[0] 026187c4
    Name:        ConsoleApplication1.Data
    MethodTable: 00214670
    EEClass:     00211ac4
    Size:        12(0xc) bytes
    File:        D:\Development Projects\Centive Solutions\SVN\trunk\CentiveSolutions.Renderers\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
    Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
        00202800  4000001        0     ...lib]], mscorlib]]      0     instance     02618a9c     _list
[1] 026187c8
    Name:        ConsoleApplication1.Data
    MethodTable: 00214670
    EEClass:     00211ac4
    Size:        12(0xc) bytes
    File:        D:\Development Projects\Centive Solutions\SVN\trunk\CentiveSolutions.Renderers\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
    Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
        00202800  4000001        0     ...lib]], mscorlib]]      0     instance     6d50950800000000     _list
[2] 026187cc
    Name:        ConsoleApplication1.Data
    MethodTable: 00214670
    EEClass:     00211ac4
    Size:        12(0xc) bytes
    File:        D:\Development Projects\Centive Solutions\SVN\trunk\CentiveSolutions.Renderers\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
    Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
        00202800  4000001        0     ...lib]], mscorlib]]      0     instance     6d50950800000000     _list
```

Here we have the value of the `_list` attribute for the 3 first elements of the array: `02618a9c`, `6d50950800000000`, `6d50950800000000`.
I suspect `6d50950800000000` to be the "null pointer".

Here we have the answer to your question: There is an array (referenced by the blocking collection (see 6.)) that contains directly the address of the `_list` we want the garbage collector to finalize.

**8** To be sure it is not changing when the line `_line = null` is executed, executes the line.

**Note**

As I've mentioned, using DumpHeap is not well suited for the current task implying value types. Why? Because value types are not in the heap but on the stack. Seeing this is very simple: try `!DumpHeap -stat -type ConsoleApplication1.Data` on the breakpoint. Result:

```
total 0 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00214c00        1           20 System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1[[ConsoleApplication1.Data, ConsoleApplication1]]
00214e24        1           36 System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1+Segment[[ConsoleApplication1.Data, ConsoleApplication1]]
00214920        1           40 System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`1[[ConsoleApplication1.Data, ConsoleApplication1]]
00214f30        1          140 ConsoleApplication1.Data[]
Total 4 objects
```

There is an array of `Data` but no `Data`. Because DumpHeap only analyses the heap. Then `!DumpArray -details 026187bc`, the pointer is still here with the same value. And if you compare the roots of the two instances we have found before (with `!GCRoot`) before executing the line and after, there will be only line removed. Indeed, the refence to the list has only be removed from 1 copy of the value type `Data`.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed info about SOS. I have never used it, but I will definitly use it now.

Comment: The value types in this case are indeed on the heap. You said it yourself, that there is an array of `Data`. That array, which is on the heap, stores the `Data` elements.

Comment: Exactly but not all the _Data_ are on the heap, because all _Data_ are not encapsulated in an array (for example, when passed as an argument of a method).